# Is it possible to delete an iCloud account

Tags: icloud

I once created an iCloud account, which I do not use. Is it possible to delete it? The reason why I would like to do it is so that I can add its email to my current iCloud account, which I am now unable to.
Note that I am not talking about the account on the iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t delete them as such, but you can “empty” them. See http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-an-Apple-ID for details.

Comment: You are welcome! De nada :)